# ReactJS How to update the state in object which is in the array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, state, setstate

Hello I have one problem that I don't know ho to solve.

I have simple formular where the user type som inputs. After that when he clicks on the Button the firstName, lastname and picture will be display under the formular. And when I click on the input it will show the address and date.

But I have problem to do that. In App.js I have a state which initialli si empty array and after click on submit button the user inputs is added to this empty array. In Suggestions.js I map the sugestions array for displaying every suggestion from the user.

In UserInputs.js I have a state where I add into state a 'visible' to false  and I want to do, when I clicked on on suggestion in a list it will display the description and date below this particular sugestion.

I want to do it like this. In App.js

```
const detail = (suggestion) => {
        
        setSuggestions([...suggestions]); //but I don't know how to set state for particular 
                                            suggestion in the array.
      };
```

My code:

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Suggestions from "./components/Suggestions";
import UserInputs from "./components/UserInputs";

function App() {
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

  const addNewSuggestion = (suggestion) => {
    setSuggestions([suggestion, ...suggestions]);
  };

  const detail = (suggestion) => {
    
    setSuggestions([...suggestions]);
  };

  console.log("suggestions", suggestions);

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <UserInputs addNewSuggestion={addNewSuggestion}></UserInputs>
      <Suggestions suggestions={suggestions} detail={detail}></Suggestions>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Suggestions.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Suggestions({ suggestions, detail }) {
  return (
    <div className="suggestion-container">
      <h1 className="suggestion-heading">Zoznam Podnetov</h1>
      {suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={suggestion.id}
            className="suggestion"
            onClick={() => detail(suggestion)}
          >
            <div className="suggestion-number">{index + 1}</div>

            <div className="suggestion-details">
              <div className="suggestion-name">
                {suggestion.firstName}
                {` ${suggestion.lastName}`}
              </div>

              <div className="suggestion-address">{suggestion.address}</div>
              {suggestion.visible ? (
                <div className="suggestion-description">
                  <p>{suggestion.description}</p>
                  <p>Podnet bol pridaný: {suggestion.date}</p>
                </div>
              ) : null}
            </div>

            <div className="suggestion-picture">
              <img
                src={suggestion.picture}
                alt="obrázok"
                className="suggestion-picture"
              ></img>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Userinputs.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function UserInputs({ addNewSuggestion }) {
  const randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);

  const [userInputs, setUserInputs] = useState({
    id: randomId,
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    address: "",
    description: "",
    picture: null,
    date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
    visible: true,
  });

  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    setUserInputs({
      ...userInputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const fileSelectHandler = (event) => {
    setUserInputs({
      ...userInputs,
      picture: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    addNewSuggestion(userInputs);

    setUserInputs({
      id: randomId,
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      address: "",
      description: "",
      picture: null,
      date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
      visible: true,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="form-container">
        <div className="row">
          <label>Meno</label>
          <input
            autoFocus
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            value={userInputs.firstName}
            onChange={onInputChange}
          ></input>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <label>Priezvisko</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            value={userInputs.lastName}
            onChange={onInputChange}
          ></input>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <label>Adresa</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="address"
            value={userInputs.address}
            onChange={onInputChange}
          ></input>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <label>Popis</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="description"
            value={userInputs.description}
            onChange={onInputChange}
          ></input>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <input type="file" onChange={fileSelectHandler}></input>
        </div>

        <button onClick={onSubmit} className="button">
          Odoslať
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: one way to go about this issue is to keep track of the index (in the array) of each suggestion (it is possible array index coincides with DOM index but not necessarily). Then to alter a particular suggestion in index `i` simply alter the array position at `i`

Comment: thank you fo your answer. Could you send me the expample of the code? because in setSuggestions I need to copy previous state and then update the current state of the particular suggestion in the array. And I'm lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can update the suggestion, where the id matches input suggestion and only update it. Please find the code below:

```
const detail = (suggestion) => { 

  let tempSuggestions = suggestions.map( (item) => {  
  if(item.id === suggestion.id) return suggestion
  return item
})
        
setSuggestions([...tempSuggestions]);                                            
}
```